# Структура Playbook для Ansible

Tags: ansible

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать отдельную "структуру" плейбука для запуска.
То есть лежит папка, в ней лежат:

1. инвентарь (стати, я так и не понял, почему инвентарем зовется список хостов)
2. несколько ямл-файлов, описывающих отдельные части деплоя
3. мастер-файл, который собирает все это воедино (и плейбук запускается из него)

Вопросы:

1. как создать такую структуру, чтобы был свой инвентарь?
2. как прокинуть переменные (vars) из одного подфайла *.ямл во все?
3. Можно ли всю эту структуру запихать в один архив (скажем, зип) и запускать через него?

Comment: Подскажите, а `python` как связан с вопросом? :)

Comment: ямл из зипа не читается

Comment: Я просто разделил все ключевые плейбуки по группам с одельными `group_vars, host_vars, inventory, ansible.cfg`, создал дефолтную групу с ролями и пробросил ссылки в остальные.

Answer (score 1):

Я не очень понял фразу:

> отдельную "структуру" плейбука для запуска

---

Используя следующую структуру `inventory`, можно определять хосты и группы переменных в зависимости от окружения.

- inventory/

  - prod/

    - p001/

      - p001.ini
      - group_vars/p001.yml
    - p002/

      - p002.ini
      - group_vars/p002.yml
    - p003/

      - p003.ini
      - group_vars/p003.yml

А в корне проекта можно создать файл отвечающий за тот или иной компонент, условный `component.yml`, который будет содержать все необходимое для работы, для других файлов будет аналогично.

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/prod/p001/p001.ini component.yml
```

Все переменные объявленные в `group_vars` относящимя к `p001` будут доступны в `component.yml`. Кроме того, данная структура будет удобна в работе с `AWX`.

Comment: то есть, если я правильно понял. То "инвентарем" называется любой файл для ансибла? То есть я могу создать папку, а в ней накидать древовидную структуру из подпапок. А в корне прописать мастер-файл?

Comment: @AntispamAntispam, нет, на сколько я понимаю, то `inventory` это именно перечень хостов, которые могут быть записаны в разных форматах - `ini`, `yml` и которым могут быть выставленны в соответствие группы переменных - [Splitting Out Host and Group Specific Data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data).

Comment: @AntispamAntispam, это то, что выхотели узнать?

Comment: лишь наполовину. Со структурой инвертори разобрались. А можно ли делать под-сткрутуры плейбука? Типа подзадачи.

Comment: @AntispamAntispam, поясните пожалуйста, я не понял вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

В общих слова, структура зависит от вашей работы и какой тип задач нужно покрыть.

Я работаю с настройкой железных серверов, с дальнейшей поддержкой из удаленно. Моя структура очень жесткая и статичная. Новый сервер добавляется в список хостов разбитых по группам. Каждая из групп принадлежит различным типам конфигурации `[hos:children]`, содержащих свои переменные в `group_var`, в добавок каждый хост имеет свой список переменных в `host_vars`.

Для Ansible критичные следующие имена директорий и файлов, которые программа ищет по спирали, начиная с текущего каталога:

- ansible.cfg
- group_vars
- host_vars
- roles

**Директории** которые конструируются через `ansible.cfg`

```
fact_caching_connection = ../var/cache
inventory = inventory
log_path = ../var/log/ansible.log
retry_files_save_path = ../var/retry
```

Весь проект разбит на 3 основные зоны: `aws`, `dc`, `site` с отдельными  `ansible.cfg`

```
~$ pwd | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev; tree -L 1 -a
ud-aggregate
.
├── Ansible
├── CHANGELOG.txt
├── doc
├── .git
├── .gitignore
├── org
├── README.md
├── scripts
└── tmp
```

- Ansible - основная часть
- doc - статичная документация
- ort - документация, генерируемая автоматических из каждого плейбука-роли
- scripts - черновые скрипты обрабатывающие `cache` сохраненный в JSON и по необходимости создающие структуры для `host_vars`
- tmp - всякого рода временные данные

Структура `Ansible`:

```
~$ pwd | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev; tree -L 2 -a
Ansible
.
├── aws
│   ├── cache
│   ├── group_vars
│   ├── host_vars
│   ├── inventory
│   ├── library
│   ├── README.org
│   └── roles
├── dc
│   ├── ansible.cfg
│   ├── ansible.log
│   ├── group_vars
│   ├── host_vars
│   ├── inventory
│   ├── library
│   ├── pl-dc-add-user.yml
│   ├── pl-dc-mt-api.yml
│   ├── pl-java.yml
│   ├── pl-ping.yml
│   ├── README.org
│   └── roles
├── default
│   ├── README.org
│   └── roles
├── site
│   ├── ansible.cfg
│   ├── group_vars
│   ├── host_vars
│   ├── inventory
│   ├── library
│   ├── pl-java.yml
│   ├── pl-ping.yml
│   ├── pl-site-absorber.yml
│   ├── pl-site-chk-tms-port.yml
│   ├── pl-site-crons.yml
│   ├── pl-site-mt-restart.yml
│   ├── pl-site-mt.yml
│   ├── pl-site-network.yml
│   ├── pl-site-signoff.yml
│   ├── pl-site-ts.yml
│   ├── README.org
│   └── roles
└── var
    ├── cache
    ├── log
    ├── retry
    └── templates
```

Организация ролей такова, что большинство из них являются "дефолтными" и линкуются в из `default`

Уникальные роли:

```
~$ find ./*/roles -maxdepth 1 -type d
./aws/roles
./dc/roles
./dc/roles/install_dc-ts
./dc/roles/install_mt-api
./default/roles
./default/roles/prelude
./default/roles/sys_cfg_facts
./default/roles/sys_cfg_upgrade_install
./default/roles/install_java
./site/roles
./site/roles/sys_cfg_grp_usr
./site/roles/sys_cfg_time
./site/roles/install_mtc
./site/roles/mender
./site/roles/sys_cfg_library
./site/roles/install_ts
./site/roles/sys_cfg_cronjobs
./site/roles/sys_cfg_security
./site/roles/install_gui
./site/roles/sys_cfg_ftp
./site/roles/install_rb
./site/roles/sys_cfg_net
./site/roles/inspector
```

Симлинки

```
~$ find ./*/roles -maxdepth 1 -type l
./dc/roles/prelude
./dc/roles/sys_cfg_facts
./dc/roles/sys_cfg_upgrade_install
./dc/roles/install_java
./site/roles/prelude
./site/roles/sys_cfg_facts
./site/roles/sys_cfg_upgrade_install
./site/roles/install_java
```

Все плейбуки содержат шебанг к `ansible-playbook` и исполняемы (`chmod +x pl-ping.yml`), что сводит запуск к одному "слову":

```
~$ cat pl-ping.yml
#!/usr/bin/ansible-playbook
---
# File     : pl-ping.yml
# Created  : <2017-12-22 Fri 16:08:30 GMT>
# Modified : <2018-2-02 Fri 13:34:21 GMT> hellseher
# Synopsis :

- hosts: all
  strategy: free
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
    - name: "ping-pong-yong"
      ping:
...
# End of pl-ping.yml
```

Что бы пропиноговать все хосты достаточно набрать:

```
~$ ./pl-ping.yml
```

Выбранный мною подход к организации проекта строго привязан к типу работы, мной выполняемой, у вас может отличатся.

---

**UPD**

> Вопросы:
>
> 1. как создать такую структуру, чтобы был свой инвентарь?
> 2. как прокинуть переменные (vars) из одного подфайла *.ямл во все?
>
> 3.Можно ли всю эту структуру запихать в один архив (скажем, зип) и запускать через него?

1. только прописав в `ansible.cfg` локально, где плейбук или глобально в `/etc/ansible.cfg`
2. создать группы, привязать переменные и хосты к необходимой группе
3. вопрос не имеет смысла, без ответа

**Ссылки**

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html
- https://leucos.github.io/ansible-files-layout
- https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Правда, он не ответил мне на такую вещь, как задать отдельный инвентарь для проекта. Да, его можно прописать при запуске. Но я бы хотел иметь одну точку входа. То есть указать пусть к мастер-файлу (run_your_playbook.yml), а все остальное ансибл сделает сам.

Comment: ну и второе, что бы я хотел получить: как шарить переменные между тасками? То есть я так и не смог это сделать (пришлось для каждой задачи внутри одного проекта прописывать одинаковые наборы vars'ов).

Comment: @AntispamAntispam Добавте свой вариант в вопрос и в какой области нужно решить задачу - сети, амазон, провизия железа и тд.